# Dynamic Var, Binding, Namespace visibility

Tags: clojure

Getting unresolved on dynamic var when called from n-levels out from originating namespace

Setup:

```
File a.clj
-----------
(ns a)

(def ^:dynamic *poof* "poof")

(def x [1 '*poof* 3])

(defn- func-wbind [new-term]
  (binding [*poof* new-term]
    (println (eval x))))

(defn with-term [term]
  (println x)
  (println (eval x)) ; <== *** FAILS HERE ***
  (func-wbind term))

File b.clj
-----------
(ns b
 (:require [a :refer :all]))

(defn woof-it []
  (with-term "woof")) 

File c.clj
-----------
(ns c
(:require [b :refer :all]))

(defn try-it []
  (woof-it))
```

Loading REPL  with 'c' and calling try-it fails on unresolved var for the dynamic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit** : Above modified and repeatable error.

Stack Trace:

```
ERROR in (endpoint-tests) (Compiler.java:6380)
Default
expected: (map? (endpoint-abstractions ep-any "www.yahoo.com"))
  actual: clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: *ph* in this context, compiling:(gl_ep/epref_tests.clj:17:1)
 at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze (Compiler.java:6380)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze (Compiler.java:6322)
    clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr$Parser.parse (Compiler.java:948)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq (Compiler.java:6560)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze (Compiler.java:6361)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze (Compiler.java:6322)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq (Compiler.java:6555)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze (Compiler.java:6361)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze (Compiler.java:6322)
    clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse (Compiler.java:5708)
    clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse (Compiler.java:5139)
    clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse (Compiler.java:3751)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq (Compiler.java:6558)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze (Compiler.java:6361)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6616)

    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6582)
    clojure.core$eval.invoke (core.clj:2852)
    gl_ep.html_extract$glg_hfm_transform$fn__5320$fn__5321.invoke (html_extract.clj:35)
    hickory.select$attr$fn__5193.invoke (select.clj:220)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:161)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:151)
    clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke (AFunction.java:29)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:408)
    hickory.select$ordered_adjacent$fn__5271.invoke (select.clj:481)
    hickory.select$select_next_loc.invoke (select.clj:134)
    hickory.select$select_next_loc.invoke (select.clj:129)
    hickory.select$select_next_loc.invoke (select.clj:127)
    hickory.select$select_locs.invoke (select.clj:143)
    hickory.select$select.invoke (select.clj:154)
    gl_ep.html_extract$hickory_get.invoke (html_extract.clj:66)
    gl_ep.html_extract$mapglg$fn__5363.invoke (html_extract.clj:76)
    clojure.core$map$fn__4207.invoke (core.clj:2485)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:42)

    clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:60)
    clojure.lang.RT.seq (RT.java:484)
    clojure.core$seq.invoke (core.clj:133)
    clojure.core$map$fn__4207.invoke (core.clj:2479)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:42)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:60)
    clojure.lang.RT.seq (RT.java:484)
    clojure.core$seq.invoke (core.clj:133)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:617)
    gl_ep.html_extract$mapglg.invoke (html_extract.clj:73)
    gl_ep.html_extract$extract.invoke (html_extract.clj:87)
    gl_ep.endpoint$abstractions.doInvoke (endpoint.clj:59)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:423)
    gl_ep.endpoint$endpoint_abstractions.doInvoke (endpoint.clj:68)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:423)
    gl_ep.epref_tests$fn__8816$fn__8817.invoke (epref_tests.clj:10)
    gl_ep.epref_tests/fn (epref_tests.clj:10)
    clojure.test$test_var$fn__7145.invoke (test.clj:701)
    clojure.test$test_var.invoke (test.clj:701)
    clojure.test$test_all_vars$fn__7149$fn__7156.invoke (test.clj:717)

    clojure.test$default_fixture.invoke (test.clj:671)
    clojure.test$test_all_vars$fn__7149.invoke (test.clj:717)
    clojure.test$default_fixture.invoke (test.clj:671)
    clojure.test$test_all_vars.invoke (test.clj:713)
    clojure.test$test_ns.invoke (test.clj:736)
    clojure.core$map$fn__4207.invoke (core.clj:2487)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval (LazySeq.java:42)
    clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq (LazySeq.java:60)
    clojure.lang.Cons.next (Cons.java:39)
    clojure.lang.RT.boundedLength (RT.java:1654)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:130)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:619)
    clojure.test$run_tests.doInvoke (test.clj:751)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:408)
    clojure.test$run_tests.invoke (test.clj:749)
```

Comment: Works for me in Clojure 1.5.1 and 1.6. My first thought would be to try again in a new REPL.

Comment: @Alex - I am in 1.5.1 and have tried multiple REPL loads to no avail

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @Alex - The var in the stack trace is called *ph*. This is from my unit testing....

Comment: Have you tested the sample code you posted? Clearly what's going on in your unit tests is much more complicated - it looks as if there's some call to `eval` happening at runtime.

Comment: @Alex The sample code was just that, a sample. In the real code I am doing an eval at the moment that I am 'binding...' *ph* to another value, which is the intent.

Comment: @Alex - I touched up the top of the message to faithfully recreate the scenario w/eval. Works fine if I load "b" into REPL, but fails on loading "c" as explained originally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `eval` a form, unqualified symbols in that form are resolved in the current namespace (as defined by `clojure.core/*ns*`) at **runtime**, *not* the namespace in which the call to `eval` was compiled. So the symbol `*poof*` is resolved in the REPL namespace. This works in namespace `b` because you did a `:refer :all` when requiring `a`, thereby creating a local alias to `a/*poof*` in `b`. There exists no such alias in `c`, and so resolving the symbol fails.

There are a couple of options to fix this. You could change the declaration of `x` to use a namespace-qualified symbol:

```
(def x [1 'a/*poof* 3])`
```

Or, you could make the call to `eval` in a binding of `*ns*` to namespace `a`.

```
(def x [1 '*poof* 3])

(defn- local-eval [x]
  (binding [*ns* (find-ns 'a)]
    (eval x)))
```

and then replace calls to `eval` with calls to `local-eval`.

See the [Clojure documentation](http://clojure.org/evaluation) for a more detailed explanation of how symbols are resolved during evaluation.

Comment: qualifying the quoted usage works. Thanks for the link as well.